# NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M in the Dell Latitude E6500

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia

How can i install NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M driver for my Dell Latitude E6500?

I downloaded NVIDIA-Linux-x86-290.10.run by searching in nvidia site.

After download I stop lightdm service and then run NVIDIA-Linux-x86-290.10.run with
`sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-290.10.run` but in install process I see error message and installation progress stops.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu X team has a [stable package PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) with the latest drivers for your card.

To install the Nvidia drivers in your system you can do so following these 3 simple steps:

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Update your sources and install the latest Nvidia driver (version 290.10)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Reboot your system with

```
sudo reboot
```

or by selecting `shutdown` on the user menu.

This method is recommended (specially for a new user) because it makes the removal and upgrade of the graphics package easyer and transparent.

It uses the same driver as you downloaded but its already packaged for your system.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Bruno Pereira's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/93815/114818).

If you're behind proxy, before adding the ppa repository, set the proxy with:

```
export https_proxy=http://yourproxy.com:8080
```

And in case your kernel source is not installed yet:

```
apt-get install build-essential linux-source linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Comment: Can you recheck the last command. `uname -r` is surrounded by backticks. Is this the command you want to run?