# Problem with display resolution using a NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M 

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, display, resolution

After following the steps of Bruno Pereira's answer in "[NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M in the Dell Latitude E6500](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93809/nvidia-quadro-nvs-160m-in-the-dell-latitude-e6500/93815#93815)". My NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M driver installed on my system without any error, but after rebooting my system when I go to my system info -> graphics, driver still is "Unknown".

My display is good in resolution 1920*1200(16:10) but graphical objects are very small and when I change the resolution, my display goes opaque. I don't know what should I do!

Comment: Can you add a link to what you are referring to?I guess you installed the proprietary Nvidia driver, which is totally okay.However,you should use the nvidia control panel (I do not know the exact name, as I am not at home and dont have Nvidia graphics here), the "normal" settings dialogue might not work in that case.

Comment: this is link of my steps:http://askubuntu.com/questions/93809/nvidia-quadro-nvs-160m-in-the-dell-latitude-e6500/93815#93815

Comment: okay please use nvidia-settings. Type it as a command in a terminal or run it from the preferences menu.

Comment: i typed nvidia-settings in terminal when nvidia settings go up alerted me some message like this "type nvidia-xconfig to config nvidia" i do that and reboot system.after rebooting X doesn't go up, my screen is only a black area!!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)