# Can't get Past Login Screen -Graphics Drivers 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics, dell

Newbie Linux user here.  I just installed Ubuntu 12.10, dual booting with Windows 8 Preview Release Build 8400 on a Dell Precision 490 workstation with Nvidia Quandro NVS 55/280 PCI graphics card.

I cannot login to Ubuntu - after entering my password and pressing enter, the screen graphics gets garbled for a few seconds, and then the screen goes black showing only the mouse cursor.  I suspect it's something to do with my Graphics Card, everything on the GUI login screen feels very sluggish.

I know what I have provided here doesn't give you much information, would appreciate it if I could get some guidance on how to provide more useful logs.

Thank you.

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/222433/44179) is a link to a answer on how to install drivers if you can't access ubuntu.

Comment: Try booting with `nomodeset`. To do this, when you get to the Grub menu, select `Advanced Options`, then the second `Recovery mode` entry, and then select `Resume normal boot`. After that install a graphics driver from `additional-drivers`.

Comment: @iSeth I tried that link, but when I got to "Additional Drivers" tab, the list was blank.  Couldn't find anything to install.

Comment: what graphics card do you have?

Comment: @iSeth Nvidia Quandro NVS 55/280 PCI

Comment: Try following the answer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/93815/44179) question.  Its for 12.04 but it should work with 12.10.

Comment: @iSeth That worked!! Thanks a lot.  Want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu X team has created a stable PPA for the Quadro NVS 160M  that should work with your graphics card too.

To Install it follow these instructions.

First you need to add the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Then Update the package list and install the driver

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Then reboot the computer with `sudo reboot`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/93815/44179)